# Context menu: I do not understand some lines of example code. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am studding android development on kotlin and I have this example of code:
https://kotlintutorialspoint.wordpress.com/2018/03/30/context-menu-using-kotlin-in-android/
I do not understand what is happening when we use these lines of code (what does kotlin do?):

```
val info = item.menuInfo as AdapterContextMenuInfo

val listPosition = info.position
```

I only know that by using these lines we will get "val name" which is using in Toast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lines don't do anything special. They are just creating new constants and assigning values to them.

The first line creates a constant called `info` and it has the value of `item.menuInfo as AdapterContextMenuInfo`. Now what is `item.menuInfo`? That is an object that contains the position of the option that was selected, as we later refer to `info.position` in the second line. On the second line, we created a constant called `listPosition` that stores the value `info.position`. We then use this index to get which option was selected using `array`.

These lines could be combined into one single statement, though less readable:

```
Toast.makeText(
    this@MainActivity, " " + selectedItemTitle + " " +
    array[(item.menuInfo as AdpaterContextMenuInfo).position]
    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

So the 3 lines are just there to show you how to get the name of the item selected in a more readable way than writing them all in one statement.

Comment: Thank you! It was usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read up on the basics of Kotlin before you start making things in it.

This is the Java equivalent of those two lines:

```
final AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
final int listPosition = info.position;
```

Kotlin doesn't require explicit type declaration, and can infer what the variable should be, so `val variableName = whatever` is usually enough.

Kotlin also has a different syntax for casting objects, as you can see by comparing it to Java. Again, you should be reading the Kotlin docs before attempting a project.

Comment: Here is some misunderstandings betwee us, so lets use 3lines of code:
val info = item.menuInfo as AdapterContextMenuInfo
        val listPosition = info.position
        val name = array[listPosition]

We search certain position (I mean string) in the array and make name equals to that string. But I do not understand how did we get “List position”

Comment: I have no idea what you don't understand then. Do you not understand how arrays work?

Comment: Here is some misunderstandings betwee us, so lets use 3lines of code:
val info = item.menuInfo as AdapterContextMenuInfo
        val listPosition = info.position
        val name = array[listPosition]

We search certain position (I mean string) in the array and make name equals to that string. But I do not understand how did we get “List position”

Comment: Look at the code. It's pretty straightforward. `item` is the MenuItem that was clicked. Each MenuItem holds a MenuInfo Object. That MenuInfo Object holds the position of that item in the overall menu.